# pysdl2 Access Violation displaying image

Tags: python, sdl-2, pysdl2

I'm trying to get started with pysdl2 on a windows machine. So far I have just got as far as copying-and-pasting the [Hello World tutorial](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/helloworld.html), just so I can see if it's actually working! It isn't.

```
import sys
import sdl2.ext

RESOURCES = sdl2.ext.Resources(__file__, "resources")

sdl2.ext.init()

window = sdl2.ext.Window("Hello World!", size=(640, 580))
window.show()

factory = sdl2.ext.SpriteFactory(sdl2.ext.SOFTWARE)
sprite = factory.from_image(RESOURCES.get_path("testimage.png"))

spriterenderer = factory.create_sprite_render_system(window)
spriterenderer.render(sprite)

processor = sdl2.ext.TestEventProcessor()
processor.run(window)

sdl2.ext.quit()
```

When I run the program, it briefly displays a window then crashes with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    spriterenderer.render(sprite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sdl2\ext\sprite.py", line 643, in render
    surface.SDL_BlitSurface(sprites.surface, None, self.surface, r)
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x03F3B000
```

although the address is different each time.

This only seems to happen on larger images - if I resize the image to `245 x 245` pixels or smaller, then it will display without complaint. I'm using Pillow for improved format support and get the same problem with `bmp`, `png` and `jpg`.

Edited to add:

Today, I've been poking at this again trying to understand. My test image that was `245x245` pixels wouldn't work any more, unless I did something between creating the spriterenderer and calling `render(sprite)` on it - I added `print sprite` between those lines out of interest to see if there was actually something in the variable and there is, and it displays. Comment out the `print` line and it fails. Then I made the same image larger, `500x500` and got the `access violation` error again. I have no idea what it going on.

Answer (score 1):

What version of SDL are you using? Is it the latest development one from Mercurial?

If so, it might be unstable and have a bug that does not allow it to run properly on Windows, in my case it's working just fine on both Arch and Windows with the stable versions.

The error returned there is a WindowsError, it probably comes from the usage of the DLL file.

If you are using an unstable version, try it with a stable one. It might work afterwards.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm using the stable 2.0.3 version from here http://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php I just dragged the .dll from the Runtime Binaries download into my system32 folder and then installed pySDL2